# Save and Load MapAnnotation pins using NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, mkmapview, nsuserdefaults, mkannotation

I need help with my MapAnnotation codes. I want to save map pins so that the user can come back to the map and see the ones he/she has placed.

However this code does not show the pins when the view loads.

Code for adding and saving pins:

```
- (void)addPinToMap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    return;



CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
[self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

 //NSMutableArray *pincoords = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCoords"];

NSMutableDictionary *pindict;

NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *pincoords = [def objectForKey:@"saveCoords"];


CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;

coordinates.latitude = touchMapCoordinate.latitude;
coordinates.longitude = touchMapCoordinate.longitude;

NSNumber* latDegrees = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:touchMapCoordinate.latitude];
NSNumber* longDegrees = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];



 [pindict setObject:latDegrees forKey:@"pinlat"];
  [pindict setObject:longDegrees forKey:@"pinlong"];








 MapAnnotation *toAdd = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];


toAdd.coordinate = coordinates;
toAdd.title = @"Svampe Spot";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:toAdd];


[pincoords addObject:pindict];

[def synchronize];


}
```

My code for loading:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];


   NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   NSMutableArray *pincoords = [def objectForKey:@"saveCoords"];

   for (NSDictionary *pindict in pincoords) {

     CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlat"] floatValue], [[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlong"] floatValue]);

    MapAnnotation *mapPin = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];





    mapPin.coordinate = coordinate;
    mapPin.title = @"Svampe Spot";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapPin];
    [def synchronize];


    [def synchronize];

 }

}
```

A solution would be much appreciated!!

CODE FOR DELETING A SPECIFIC ANNOTATION:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)mapViewpin
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {


NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *pincoords = [def objectForKey:@"saveCoords"];

for (NSDictionary *pindict in pincoords) {

 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                               [[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlat"] doubleValue],
                                                               [[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlong"] doubleValue]);

 MapAnnotation *mapPin = mapViewpin.annotation;

 mapPin.coordinate =coordinate;

 [self.mapView removeAnnotation:mapPin];
 [def removeObjectForKey:@"saveCoords"];

 [def synchronize];
}


}
```

This deletes them all. How do i make it specific for the annotation whos button is tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volker's answer does point out one important issue:

The first time the user adds a pin, there will be no array already saved in the user defaults so `pinCoords` will be `nil`.  Therefore, the `addObject` calls on the array will do nothing.  You need to handle this case by allocating an empty array if it's `nil` so you can add objects to it.

However, there are still other issues in `addPinToMap:` that will prevent the code from working even after fixing the above:

1. The `pindict` variable is *declared* but never *allocated*.  This will either lead to a crash when you call `setObject:forKey:` on it or do nothing.  You need to allocate the `pindict` variable.
2. With `NSUserDefaults`, `objectForKey:` will return an *immutable* object.  That means even though `pincoords` is declared as an `NSMutableArray`, `objectForKey:` will return an `NSArray` (if it finds a value for the key in user defaults).  Therefore, the `addObject` calls will again fail (this time with a crash) since you can't add objects to an `NSArray`.  What you need to do is take the result of `objectForKey:` and make a mutable version of it by calling `mutableCopy`.
3. After adding the new coordinates to `pinCoords`, the code *does not save the updated array back to user defaults*.  It just calls `synchronize`.  Before calling `synchronize`, you need to actually save the array to user defaults by calling `setObject:forKey:`.

After making all the above changes, the code should work.

I also recommend two more changes to improve the code (though these aren't preventing it from working):

1. Instead of saving the coordinates as `float` values, save them as `double`.  The latitude and longitude in Core Location are actually of type `double` (`CLLocationDegrees` is actually a double).  You'll also get better precision.  So in `addPinToMap:`, use `numberWithDouble` instead of `numberWithFloat` and in `viewDidLoad`, use `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue`.
2. In `viewDidLoad`, inside the `for` loop, you are calling `synchronize` twice.  These calls are pointless -- remove them.

The final, updated code in `addPinToMap:` would be this:

```
- (void)addPinToMap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

    NSMutableDictionary *pindict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *pincoords = [[def objectForKey:@"saveCoords"] mutableCopy];
    if (pincoords == nil)
    {
        pincoords = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;

    coordinates.latitude = touchMapCoordinate.latitude;
    coordinates.longitude = touchMapCoordinate.longitude;

    NSNumber* latDegrees = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:touchMapCoordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber* longDegrees = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];

    [pindict setObject:latDegrees forKey:@"pinlat"];
    [pindict setObject:longDegrees forKey:@"pinlong"];

    MapAnnotation *toAdd = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];

    toAdd.coordinate = coordinates;
    toAdd.title = @"Svampe Spot";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:toAdd];

    [pincoords addObject:pindict];

    [def setObject:pincoords forKey:@"saveCoords"];

    [def synchronize];
}
```

The updated `for` loop in `viewDidLoad` would be like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *pindict in pincoords) {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        [[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlat"] doubleValue], 
        [[pindict objectForKey:@"pinlong"] doubleValue]);

    MapAnnotation *mapPin = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];

    mapPin.coordinate = coordinate;
    mapPin.title = @"Svampe Spot";

    [self.map addAnnotation:mapPin];
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. How would you go about deleting a map annotation now. I have tried with the calloutaccessorycontroltapped, where the button inside the annotation will delete the annotation by doing this: [self.mapview removeAnnotation:annotation]; But that doesn't work. I assume I have to delete the saved coordinates for that specific annotation? Do i load the saved coordinates then apply them to the annotation and then remove it?

Comment: Right now, you're only storing the coordinates in the dictionary.  You could also store some string that uniquely identifies the annotation (maybe title).  Then, loop through the saved annotations and check their title.  If it matches, delete it from the array and save it back.  I don't recommend comparing coordinates. This is really worth a separate question though.  Also, I should mention that user defaults is probably ok for small data but may want to switch to a plist or a real db if you're planning to let user save hundreds of annotations.

Comment: Can i do that if all my annotations have the same title?

Comment: No, as I said, you need to have some unique id attached to each annotation.  Ask a new question if you're having trouble coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initially user des contain no mutable array for the key. So when accessing the object for the key do check if non nil is returned and otherwise create a new mutable array for filling in the points.

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue with removing just one of the markers, Anna is right and you have to add a line like such to your creation method for an identifier to look for:

```
[pindict setObject:NAME_OF_YOUR_MARKER_TITLE forKey:@"name"];
```

And then do the following to see if it exists, remove it from the array of locations and then save the data:

```
 myMapAnnotation *selectedAnnotation = mapViewpin.annotation;

    //Iterate through the location markers
    for (int i = 0; i<pincoords.count; i++) {

        if ([pincoords[i] containsObject: selectedAnnotation.title]) {

            //Create a new mutable array to work with
            NSMutableArray *pincoords = [[def objectForKey:@"saveCoords"]mutableCopy];

            //Remove the marker
            [pincoords removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedAnnotation];

            //Update the data
            [def setObject:pincoords forKey:@"saveCoords"];
        }

        //Sync outside the loop
        [def synchronize];

    }
```