# How can I save the users annotations?

Tags: xcode, swift, mkannotation

Hi I am new to swift and coding in general so excuse me if I dont understand or ask stupid questions.
I am trying to save the pins that the user ads on the map and I cant find out how, this is my code so far, the pins are added but when I close the app and re open it the app "forgets" the pin: 
}

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {


        var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)

      var newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)            
        var newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    newAnnotation.coordinate = newCoordinate

    newAnnotation.title = "new place"

    newAnnotation.subtitle = "subtitle"

    mapView.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)

    }
```

I tried adding this in the viewdidload but it doesn't work so I've probably got something wrong:
 `

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("newAnnotation", forKey: "newCoordinate")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("newAnnotation")
```

Comment: Are you planning to save a single annotation or multiple annotations?  I don't think you'll be able to save an id<MKAnnotation> object as-is with NSUserDefaults (it only supports limited types).  You'll need to save as NSData or NSDictionary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468053/save-and-load-mapannotation-pins-using-nsmutablearray for an example (Objective-C).

Comment: Anyway, the code shown in viewDidLoad doesn't work because you're giving setObject the _string_ "newAnnotation" to save (not the object named newAnnotation).  The call to objectForKey does nothing since the result is not being used (no variable is being assigned that value: `let x = ...objectForKey(...)`).

Comment: Thank you @Anna for answering. I am trying to add multiple annotations but I dont quite understand what I need to do (even to change the <MKAnnotation> object to a NSData or NSDictionary) as I am a real beginner :( could you please tell me some more, or maybe ad sample code if thats not asking too much? thanks again!